# Creating reusable code with BeautifulSoup and Classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, beautifulsoup

I'm building a web scraper to search various websites for links to news articles. To do this, I'm using BeautifulSoup to parse the pages, then extracting links from the pages for use in another function down the line. The trouble is, websites build their html differently. To try and stick to the principles of writing functions with the fewest repeated lines of code as possible, I have created a Class for the website sources, where I can put the custom html data for the function to use as it extracts urls.   Where I'm struggling is how to store and call the data. If I want to say:

```
#Website 1 
url = page.find("div", {"class": "tags absolute"}).find("a").string.strip()
#Website 2 
url = page.find("ul").find("li").find("a").string.strip()
```

So much of that is the same. I'd much rather say:

```
Website1.url_source = page.find("div", {"class": "tags absolute"}).find("a").string.strip()
Website2.url_source = page.find("ul").find("li").find("a").string.strip()
url = WebsiteN.url_source
```

This doesn't work however, as the code sees the whole thing as a string. I think I'm approaching this the wrong way, but I don't want to build a custom function for every website as that won't scale efficiently as I expand. What is the best way to handle this?

Running the code as above yielded no results, as Python read the command as a string and failed to execute it. I want to avoid using "eval()" at all costs.

I played with the idea of listing the strings only, e.g.

```
Website2.url_source = '"ul", "li", "a"'
url_source = [x.strip() for x in Website2.url_source]
url = page.find(url_source[0]).find(url_source[1]).find(url_source[2]).string.strip()
```

But since the nature of the html is that it nests differently (e.g. Website1 has two levels of "Find", and Website2 has three), that wouldn't work in the same way. I could create a constructor method to say "for x in url_source build a string of '.find(x)' but not sure that's useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class that represents a website and contains the necessary data for extracting the url source data. For example:

```py
class Website:
    def __init__(self, name, url_source):
        self.name = name
        self.url_source = url_source

website1 = Website("Website1", page.find("div", {"class": "tags absolute"}).find("a").string.strip())
website2 = Website("Website2", page.find("ul").find("li").find("a").string.strip())

url = website1.url_source
```

Comment: My other issue is that I'm storing the class data in an INI file so I don't have to hard code all the sources into the function itself. This is read as a string when assigned to the class attribute. Is there a way to tell python to store data outside of the function but still execute it as code not a string?

Comment: Wouldn't reading it as a dict and then passing to the python function suffice?

Comment: You mean have a dict in a code module that has the class values as static, then assign them in when required, rather than using an INI?